# How to solve drill down highcharts that are not working?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, yii2, drilldown

I want to make highcharts multiple drill down. The 1st is faculty, 2nd drill is department and the 3rd is major. I took data from database. But when I run my codes, the result was not working as I expected. The drill down chart appeared not perfectly like the picture below:

[image]

The result that I expected is like this picture below. I make the chart below by typing manually like this link http://jsfiddle.net/rhhh2sg3/1/

[image]

but I want to make the chart not manually typed, because I want to take data from database.

Here is the table that I put to highcharts :

**facultyin2011**

[image]

**department2011**

[image]

**major2011**

[image]

Maybe, there was something wrong in my codes below:

**CONTROLLER**

```
class MagisterrinciController extends Controller
    {
         public function actionIndex()
    {


//data usia fakultas
        $faculty = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Faculty'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $age1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();
        $age1 = array_map('floatval', $age1);

        foreach ($age1 as $key => $age1_value) {
            $age1[$key] = [
                'name' => 'Fakultas',
                'y' => $age1_value,
                'drilldown' => 'department1'
            ];
        };

        $age2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();              


        $age2 = array_map('floatval', $age2);

         foreach ($age2 as $key => $age2_value) {
            $age2[$key] = [
                'name' => 'Fakultas',
                'y' => $age2_value,
                'drilldown' => 'department2'
            ];
        };



        $data['ageforfacultystudent'] = json_encode($faculty);
        $data['age1'] = json_encode($age1);
        $data['age2'] = json_encode($age2);


// next
        $department = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Department'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agedepartment1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();
         $agedepartment1 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment1);

        foreach ($agedepartment1 as $key => $agedepartment1_value) {
                $agedepartment1[$key] = [
                'name' => 'A'.($key+1),
                'y' => $agedepartment1_value,
                'drilldown' => 'major1'
            ];
            };



        $agedepartment2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();



        $agedepartment2 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment2);
        foreach ($agedepartment2 as $key => $agedepartment2_value) {
                $agedepartment2[$key] = [
                'name' => 'B'.($key+1),
                'y' => $agedepartment2_value,
                'drilldown' => 'major2'
            ];
            };


        $data['agefordepartmentstudent'] = json_encode($department);
        $data['agedepartment1'] = json_encode($agedepartment1);
        $data['agedepartment2'] = json_encode($agedepartment2);


//next

        $majorstudent = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['major'])
            ->from('major2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $agemajor1 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor1);
        $agemajor2 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor2);


        $data['ageformajorstudent'] = json_encode($majorstudent);
        $data['agemajor1'] = json_encode($agemajor1);
        $data['agemajor2'] = json_encode($agemajor2);



        return $this->render('index',$data);
        }
```

**MY VIEW INDEX**

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    $('#containers').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: $ageforfacultystudent

        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: 'lessthan25',
                data: $age1,

            },
            {
                name: 'btween25to29',
                data: $age2,

            }],

        drilldown: {

            series: [{
                id: 'department1',
                name: 'lessthan25',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Departemen',
                    data: $agedepartment1,
                    drilldown: 'major1'
                }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                id: 'department2',
                name: 'btween25to29',
                data: [
                {
                    name: 'Departemen',
                    data: $agedepartment2,
                    drilldown: 'major2'
                }
                ]
            },
            {

                id: 'major1',
                data: $agemajor1
            },
            {

                id: 'major2',
                data: $agemajor2
            }]
        }
    })
});
```

I also do not know how to categorize the department since the department is the sub of faculty.
I could categorize the faculty like the example below because the faculty chart is not the sub of any chart.

The example is like this:

```
$('#containers').highcharts({


 chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        **categories: $ageforfacultystudent**

    },
```

It is the same problem with table major. How to categorize major to the chart since major is sub of department?

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: you are closer ,add  `<?php print_r($age1)?>` and rest in pastbin, let me go through it

Comment: here it is https://pastebin.com/saGeSuZ2 @Deep3015

Comment: see `[drilldown] => major1` drill down should not match .it should be unique. in each array drilldown  are matching

Comment: how to make them unique? Because I don't know how to categorize the drill down chart @Deep3015

Comment: it will be like `foreach ($age1 as $key => $age1_value) {
            $age1[$key] = [
                'name' => 'Fakultas',
                'y' => $age1_value,
                'drilldown' => 'department1_'.$key
            ];
        };`

Comment: the chart can't be drilled when I tried that code @Deep3015

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139650/discussion-between-deep-3015-and-dewinataria).

Comment: Halo @Deep3015 Have you found the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to differentiate categories in highcharts drilldown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167724/how-to-differentiate-categories-in-highcharts-drilldown)

Comment: @Deep3015 could you please check my chat? Because sometimes, the chat notification doesn't appear